# Error after package was removed

Tags: flutter

I removed package from my `pubcpeck.yaml`, but now I get error when I try to compile the app.

```
compiler message: Error: Could not resolve the package 'medcorder_audio' in 'package:medcorder_audio/medcorder_audio.dart'.
```

this is in my `pubscpeck.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  audioplayer:
```

There is no import to 'package:medcorder_audio/medcorder_audio.dart anywhere in my files.

I tried `pub cache repair` to no avail.

edit:

I tried to remove `audioplayer` package as well and now I get

```
compiler message: Error: Could not resolve the package 'audioplayer' in 'package:audioplayer/audioplayer.dart'.
```

Comment: try `flutter packages get` on terminal and then run

Comment: I did that, to no avail

Comment: Did you get an error message? You could try `flutter clean`. `pub cache repair` is very seldom necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should drop the build directory in the root projet before run your project